# Bash for loop create folders; do I have to escape some chars?

Tags: bash

I want to create 5 files with the same name but with an incremental counter.

If I do:

```
for i in {1..5}; do touch hallo_$i; done
```

I get `hallo_1`, `hallo_2`, `hallo_3`, etc.

If I do:

```
for i in {1..5}; do touch company-price-$i_spec.rb; done
```

I get: `company-price-.rb`

Do I have to escape something? Could it be that bash thinks I want to remove/subtract from the `$i` variable?

If I escape `.` and `-` I still got the same result.
Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the braced form of variable expansion:

```
for i in {1..5}; do touch company-price-${i}_spec.rb; done
```

otherwise, `bash` will see `$i_spec` as a variable expansion, not `$i`.

From `bash` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}. The value of 
parameter is substituted. The braces are required when parameter is a
positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is 
followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its name.
```